# Markov chain in a finite state space

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We consider the proof of Lemma $2$ (picture below, from the following paper: [https://www.math.arizona.edu/~sethuram/notes/wi_mart1.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Esethuram/notes/wi_mart1.pdf)). I am having troubles understanding why $\text{Range}(I-P)^{\perp}=\text{Null}(I-P^*)$ is a subset of $\{c\pi,c \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^{\Sigma}$ such that $u\in \text{Null}(I-P^*)$ this will imply that for all $y \in \Sigma,\sum_{x \in \Sigma}u(x)p(x,y)=u(y)$ (in a sense it's invariant measure, but taking values in $\mathbb{R}$), but I can't see why this will imply that $u/\pi$ is constant?

[image]

Comment: When citing a Lemma, please say what is the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is the transition matrix of an irreducible Markov chain, then $I-P$
and $I-P^*$ have a one dimensional kernel. See. e.g., Lemma 1.16 (page 12) and Cor. 1.17 (page 13) in [1]. Thus the kernel of $I-P$ consists of constant functions, and the kernel of $I-P^*$ contains only constant multiples of the stationary measure $\pi$, see Exercise 1.11 in [1] for another proof.

Additional remark: For an irreducible Markov chain, the directed graph obtained by introducing an edge from $x$ to $y$ iff $p(x,y)>0$ is strongly connected, i.e. for every pair of states $x,z$ there is a path from $x$ to $z$ and vice versa. This means that once you establish that $$u(x)/\pi(x)=u(y)/\pi(y) \quad (*)$$ holds   when $p(x,y)>0$, the same equality holds for every pair of states, as (*) is a transitive relation.

[1] https://yuvalperes.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times-2/
https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf

Comment: I like the proof of Exercise 1.11 and I tried to apply it to the above lemma, taking $u \in \text{Null}(I-P^*)$ which will imply that $\forall y \in \Sigma, \sum_{x \in \Sigma}u(x)p(x,y) =u(y).$ If we let $q$ be such that $u(q)/\pi(q)=\min_{x \in \Sigma}u(x)/\pi(x)$ then $$u(q) =\sum_{x \in \Sigma}u(x)p(x,q) \geq \sum_{x \in \Sigma}\pi(x)\frac{u(q)}{\pi(q)}p(x,q) \geq \frac{u(q)}{\pi(q)} \pi(q) \geq u(q)$$ so for all $x \in \Sigma$ such that $p(x,q)>0$ we have $u(x)/\pi(x)=u(q)/\pi(q).$

Comment: I can't see how to deduce that for all $x \in \Sigma,u(x)/\pi(x)=u(q)/\pi(q)$

Comment: @john I added a remark to my answer about this. One must make some assumption, either irreducibility or (at least) the existence of just one communicating class, to get uniqueness of the stationary measure.

Comment: Can we also deduce the result by mentioning that since there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that for all $x \in \Sigma,p^n(x,q)>0,$ and the argument in the first comment works by simple induction and replacing $p(x,q)$ by $p^n(x,q)$

Comment: Yes, that works just as well.